Combinatorics Permutations/Cycles question
Suppose $n\geq 5$. How many permutations of the set with $n$ elements are there such that some cycle contains elements 1,2,3, and a different cycle contains 4 and 5?
I have seen the solution to this problem, but the solution I have uses induction and just says to "guess" that the answer is $n!/60$. I have absolutely no idea the intuition behind coming up with this myself and was wondering why this is the case. Thanks!

We get $Q_5 = 3!/3 \times 2!/2 = 2$ when $n=5$. We have for $n\ge 6$ that $Q_n = (n-1) Q_{n-1} + Q_{n-1} = n Q_{n-1}$ as we can insert the $n$ value on $(n-1)$ locations of the factorization into cycles of an admissible permutation of $n-1$ or make it into a fixed point being on a cycle of its own. Unroll the recursion to get $n!/5! \times 2 = n!/60.$

There are only two cycles of the set ${1,2,3}.$

what does it mean to "unroll the recursion"? I understand the logic behind the first and second parts, but im unclear as to how the last line leads to the answer.

Unrolling is where you keep substituting the RHS into the recursion. You get $Q_n = n(n-1) Q_{n-2} = n (n-1) (n-2) Q_{n-3}$ and so on all the way to $Q_5.$

You asked for intuition, so you're not getting a rigorous proof here.
Generate a random permutation $\pi$ in "cycle order," as follows:
Shuffle a deck of cards numbered $\left\{1, \dots, n\right\}$.
The first card drawn is assigned as the value of $\pi(1)$.
The second card drawn is $\pi(\pi(1))$.
The third card drawn is $\pi(\pi(\pi(1)))$.
Etc.
If at any point we try to assign a value to $\pi(n)$ but it's already assigned, instead stop, find the smallest $i$ such that $\pi(i)$ is not assigned, and assign it to $\pi(i)$. The next value then gets assigned to $\pi(\pi(i))$, and so on.
The intuition is that (1) this generates a permutation uniformly at random, because changing the order of the deck always changes the resulting permutation; and (2) for the purposes of deciding whether the permutation satisfies the property "some cycle contains elements 1,2,3, and a different cycle contains 4 and 5," you can basically ignore the cards $6, 7, \dots, n$. So it's enough to observe that of the 120 possible orderings of the cards $\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\right\}$, only 2 -- that is, 1/60th -- of them result in a permutation that satisfies the property.
